# Spring Boot using Jersey + Actuator

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jersey, spring-boot-actuator

I am not able to get Actuator working with Spring Boot + Jersey framework. I tried below approach with Spring 1.5.3.RELEASE -

1. Included below dependency in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. changed Jersey application path to "/api" by adding below configuration in `application.properties` file.

   > spring.jersey.application-path=api

Please advise how can this done working. I am also open to get this working with Spring 2.x

Comment: can you supply a little more information? are there any errors?

Comment: try with spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE. It should work

Comment: There seemed to be some issue with asm-packages during server startup while deploying it on Liberty server. After excluding asm-packages from spring boot web in parent, the server start up was clean and the issue got resolved. <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm-all-repackaged</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>